# Parent DIV to match Child height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I am building a single page website using bootstrap.  The problem I am running into is, that I have a parent section where the height is set to 100% and is not contained.

However the rest of the content in the section is contained. So everything in the container is overflowing into the next section.  I want the parent section that is not contained to match the height of the child. I have tried using overflow:auto, however, I do not want a scrollbar to appear when the content is clipped.

Here is my code.

```
#map {
  border-top:2px solid #6d7873;
  background: #d7dbd9;
  padding-top:85px;
  height:100%;
  min-height: auto;
}

#regions_div {
  min-height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #a1aaa6;
}

#dash {
  border-top:2px solid #6d7873;
  background: #bcc2bf;
  padding-top:85px;
  height:100%;
  min-height: auto;
}

<!-- Map Section -->
  <section id="map">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div id="regions_div"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 well">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 well">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>

<!--Dashboard Section-->
   <section id="dash">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2>Disaster Maps</h2>
          <hr />
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-md" href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Disaster Map</a> &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Disaster Dashboard</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Please add all your CSS code that is used

Comment: @Grantly The CSS is above the HTML.  Thats all the CSS that corresponds.  The rest is being controlled by default bootstrap

Comment: #map is the container of your whole application? Then you can try by #map { height: 100vh; } instead "100%".

Answer (score 0):

All Bootstrap classes have a specific purpose and place in the DOM tree. There were a couple of **[`.container`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)s** were placed under the `<section>` tags. There's 2 things about BS `.container`:

1. There should be only one `.container` or `.container-fluid` per page.
2. The `.container` or `.container-fluid` purpose is to wrap around everything in the page.

That would explain why content was bleeding out, because `.container` can only exert its influence on its own descendants.

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#map {
  border-top: 2px solid #6d7873;
  background: #d7dbd9;
  padding-top: 85px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#regions_div {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #a1aaa6;
}

#dash {
  border-top: 2px solid #6d7873;
  background: #bcc2bf;
  padding: 85px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
}

article.content:first-of-type {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
}

.row+.row .content {
  margin: -10px auto 0;
}

hr {
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'>



<main class="container">
  <!-- Map Section -->
  <section id="map">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <article id="regions_div"></article>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <article class='content'>
        <div class="col-md-12 well">

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
      <article class='content'>
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!--Dashboard Section-->
  <section id='dash'>

    <div class="row">
      <article class='content'>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Disaster Maps</h2>
          <hr />
          <a class="btn btn-link btn-md" href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Disaster Map</a> &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Disaster Dashboard</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>

  </section>
</main>
<footer></footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
```